# Anova: Warning: In summary.rq(x, se = se, covariance = TRUE) : 2 non-positive fis

Tags: r, quantreg

I ran the following script to analyse a nonparametric quantile regression using `quantreg` package:

```
library (quantreg)

model.q = rq(Y_var ~ X1_var + X2_var + X3_var,
             data = wideformat_data,
             tau = 0.5)
summary(model.q)
model.nullq = rq(Y_var ~ 1,
                 data = wideformat_data,
                 tau = 0.5)

anova(model.q, model.nullq)
```

All Y and X variables were continuous and standardised. As result from `anova ( )`, a warning message was displayed:

```
Warning:
In summary.rq(x, se = se, covariance = TRUE) : 2 non-positive fis
```

Does anyone know why it occurred and how to handle with it?

Answer (score 1):

It's generally harmless:

> 7. [Non-positive fis]  "What does the message "Non-positive fis" mean?
>
>    When method ="nid" is used in summary local density estimates are
>      made at    each x_i value, in some cases these estimates can be
>      negative and if so    they are set to zero.  This is generally
>      harmless, leading to a somewhat    conservative (larger) estimate of
>      the standard errors, however if the    reported number of non-positive
>      fis is large relative to the sample size    then it is an indication
>      of misspecification of the model.
>      (http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/~roger/research/rq/FAQ)